I try getTransaction and save to DB, I can't find accountKeys in message, only staticAccountKeys
// Solana WebSocket URL
const WS_URL = process.env.SOLANA_WS_URL || 'https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/';
const connection = new Connection(WS_URL, 'confirmed');
const RAYDIUM_AMM_PROGRAM_ID = new PublicKey(process.env.RAYDIUM_AMM_PROGRAM_ID);

async function subscribeRaydium() {
    console.log("Listening for new Raydium LP transactions...");
    connection.onLogs(RAYDIUM_AMM_PROGRAM_ID, async (log) => {
        try {
            if (log.logs.some(line => line.includes('InitializeInstruction2') || line.includes('CreatePool'))) {
                console.log("New AMM LP transaction found!");
                const signature = log.signature;
                const tokenData = await processRaydiumLpTransaction(connection, signature);

                if (tokenData) {
                    const sniperConfig = {
                        baseToken: process.env.BASE_TOKEN,
                        targetToken: tokenData.coinMint,
                        buyAmount: parseFloat(process.env.BUY_AMOUNT) || 1,
                        sellTargetPrice: parseFloat(process.env.SELL_TARGET_PRICE) || 2,
                        tokenData: tokenData
                    };

                    console.log(`Launching sniper for token ${sniperConfig.targetToken} with buy amount ${sniperConfig.buyAmount}`);
                    SniperManager.addSniper(sniperConfig);
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error processing log:", error.message);
        }
    }, 'confirmed');
}

// Asynchronous function to process LP transactions on Raydium
async function processRaydiumLpTransaction(connection, signature) {
    try {
        // Fetch transaction details by its signature
        const transactionDetails = await connection.getTransaction(signature, {
            commitment: 'confirmed',
            maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0,
        });

        console.log("--------------------------------",transactionDetails,"--------------------------");

        // Check if transaction details were found
        if (!transactionDetails) {
            console.error('No transaction details found for signature:', signature);
            return; // Exit the function if no details are found
        }

        // Extract the message from the transaction
        const message = transactionDetails.transaction?.message;
        console.log("transactionDetails.transaction?.message")
        
        // Check for the presence of message and accountKeys array
        if (!message || !Array.isArray(message.staticAccountKeys)) {
            console.error("accountKeys is undefined or not an array");
            return; // Exit the function if accountKeys is missing or not an array
        }
        console.log("Transaction Message:", message);

        // Convert account keys to string format
        const accounts = message.staticAccountKeys.map(key => key.toString()) || [];

        // Check if account keys are present
        if (accounts.length === 0) {
            console.error("No account keys found.");
            return; // Exit the function if no account keys are found
        }

        console.log("Accounts:", accounts);

        // Check for the presence of instructions in the message
        if (!message.instructions) {
            console.warn("Instructions are missing in this transaction.");
            return; // Exit the function if instructions are missing
        }

        // Loop through all instructions in the message
        for (const ix of message.instructions) {
            // Check if programIdIndex is within bounds of the accounts array
            if (ix.programIdIndex >= accounts.length) {
                console.error("programIdIndex out of bounds:", ix.programIdIndex);
                continue; // Skip to the next iteration if the index is out of bounds
            }

            // Get the program ID from the accounts array
            const programId = accounts[ix.programIdIndex];
            
            // Check if the program is Raydium AMM and if instruction data is present
            if (programId === RAYDIUM_AMM_PROGRAM_ID.toString() && ix.data.length > 0) {
                // Extract token data from the instruction
                const tokenData = extractTokenData(ix, accounts);
                
                // If token data is successfully extracted, save it to MongoDB
                if (tokenData) {
                    await saveToMongo(tokenData);
                    return tokenData; // Return the extracted data
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        // Log any errors that occur during processing
        console.error('Error fetching/processing transaction:', error.message);
    } 
}

// Helper function to extract token data from instruction
function extractTokenData(ix, accounts) {
    try {
        // Extract various mint and account details from the instruction
        const mint0 = accounts[ix.accounts[8]];
        const mint1 = accounts[ix.accounts[9]];
        const lpTokenMint = accounts[ix.accounts[7]];
        const deployer = accounts[ix.accounts[17]];
        const poolId = accounts[ix.accounts[4]];
        const baseVault = accounts[ix.accounts[10]];
        const quoteVault = accounts[ix.accounts[11]];
        const ammAuthority = accounts[ix.accounts[5]];
        const ammTarget = accounts[ix.accounts[13]];
        const ammOpenOrder = accounts[ix.accounts[6]];
        const marketProgram = accounts[ix.accounts[15]];
        const marketId = accounts[ix.accounts[16]];

        // Return an object containing the extracted token data
        return {
            programId: new PublicKey(accounts[ix.accounts[0]]).toString(),
            ammId: new PublicKey(poolId).toString(),
            ammAuthority: new PublicKey(ammAuthority).toString(),
            ammOpenOrders: new PublicKey(ammOpenOrder).toString(),
            lpMint: new PublicKey(lpTokenMint).toString(),
            coinMint: new PublicKey(mint0).toString(),
            pcMint: new PublicKey(mint1).toString(),
            coinVault: new PublicKey(baseVault).toString(),
            pcVault: new PublicKey(quoteVault).toString(),
            ammTargetOrders: new PublicKey(ammTarget).toString(),
            serumMarket: new PublicKey(marketId).toString(),
            serumProgram: new PublicKey(marketProgram).toString(),
            deployer: new PublicKey(deployer).toString()
        };
    } catch (error) {
        // Log any errors that occur during token data extraction
        console.error("Error extracting token data:", error.message);
        return null; // Return null if extraction fails
    }
}

That gets only staticAccountKeys, I need to accountkeys

message: MessageV0 {
header: [Object],
staticAccountKeys: [Array],
recentBlockhash: 'FZJWcGc9AQsHDbNhKw3eQakeg8rpDHL2YUVinXi2P4LH',
compiledInstructions: [Array],
addressTableLookups: [Array]
},
Where is accountKeys

The accountKeys field is renamed to staticAccountKeys in web3.js, so just look at staticAccountKeys.
Here's the code that changes the field name: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/a240574ec6f0776e002fcb64a3d5af8b27e27e4d/src/connection.ts#L479
